# Reference point for the directions

Tags: rotation

Are directions [North, South, West, East] derived from Earth's rotation around its axis? What makes north north and the south south? Is it arbitrary or is there some specific reference point?

Comment: Why do you think so? How long do you think do the directions N,E,W and S exist in usage? How long do people generally assume that earth rotates?

Comment: Hello, Bill.  This questiion isn't about astronomy, so I've voted to "close",  but, Yes, they are derived from the rotational axis.   Some things are arbitrary, such as the convention to put North at the top of maps.